# Twenty Ten Theme: Replace the Logo by a picture without moving the code

Tags: themes, plugins, theme-twenty-ten, logo

I would like to replace the twenty ten's theme logo (text) by a picture, Is there any plugin allowing me to do that.
I know how to do it, but every time wordpress gets updated (often) the code comes back to how it was before I changed it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to make a child theme and simply add in the twentyten header.php with a link to your image.

How to make child theme, http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

It would be something like this ( under the branding div.)

```
<div id="branding" role="banner">
<div id="logo"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/YourImage.png" alt=""/></div></div><!-- #branding -->
```

Comment: Your suggestion is to use a child theme which is great but in your code snippet, you used `bloginfo( 'template_url' );` which returns parent theme URL! Don't you think it's contradictory?

Btw, WordPress recommends `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`